# Rotating Feature in Vector Layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, rotate

I am using QGIS 3.4.  I am new in gis and I am trying to rotate a feature of a vector layer.

Code:

```
for ft in feat:
    vlayer.startEditing()
    the_geom = ft.geometry()

    pt = ft.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    the_geom.rotate(-90, pt)
    ft.setGeometry(the_geom)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    vlayer.commitChanges()
    break
```

The geometry of the feature seems to change. However, I can not see any difference on the canvas.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is a "crs layer"?

Comment: Sorry you are right, it's a vector layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. For anyone who would like to check the solution:

```
for ft in feat:
    vlayer.startEditing()
    the_geom = ft.geometry()
    pt = ft.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    the_geom.rotate(180, pt)
    vlayer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ 0 : the_geom })
    vlayer.commitChanges()
    break
```